# Apache Ignite mongo configuration using spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, ignite

I am introducing Apache Ignite in our application as cache system as well as for computation. I have configured spring application using following configuration class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class IgniteConfig {

    @Value("${ignite.config.path}")
    private String ignitePath;

    @Bean(name="cacheManager")
    public SpringCacheManager cacheManager(){
        SpringCacheManager springCacheManager = new SpringCacheManager();
        springCacheManager.setConfigurationPath(ignitePath);
        return springCacheManager;
    }
}
```

Using it like

```
@Override
@Cacheable("cache1")
public List<Channel>  getAllChannels(){
    List<Channel> list = new ArrayList<Channel>();
    Channel c1 = new Channel("1",1);
    Channel c2 = new Channel("2",2);
    Channel c3 = new Channel("3",3);
    Channel c4 = new Channel("4",4);
    list.add(c1);
    list.add(c2);
    list.add(c3);
    list.add(c4);
    return list;
}
```

Now I want to add write-through and read-through feature. I could not find any documentation to connect ignite to mongo.

The idea is not to talk to db directly but through ignite using write behind feature.

EDIT-----------------------

As suggested I implemented

```
public class ChannelCacheStore extends CacheStoreAdapter<Long, Channel> implements Serializable {

    @Override
    public Channel load(Long key) throws CacheLoaderException {
        return getChannelDao().findOne(Channel.mongoChannelCode, key);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(Cache.Entry<? extends Long, ? extends Channel> entry) throws CacheWriterException {
        getChannelDao().save(entry.getValue());
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Object key) throws CacheWriterException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Delete not supported");
    }

    private ChannelDao getChannelDao(){
        return SpringContextUtil.getApplicationContext().getBean(ChannelDao.class);
    }
}
```

And added this CacheStore into cache configuration like below :

```
<property name="cacheConfiguration">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                <property name="name" value="channelCache"/>
                <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
                <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
                <property name="backups" value="1"/>
                <property name="readThrough" value="true"/>
                <!-- Sets flag indicating whether write to database is enabled. -->
                <property name="writeThrough" value="true"/>
                <!-- Enable database batching. --> 
                <!-- Sets flag indicating whether write-behind is enabled. -->
                <property name="writeBehindEnabled" value="true"/>
                <property name="cacheStoreFactory">
                    <bean class="javax.cache.configuration.FactoryBuilder$SingletonFactory">
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <bean class="in.per.amt.ignite.cache.ChannelCacheStore"></bean>
                        </constructor-arg>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
```

But now getting class cast exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.cache.interceptor.SimpleKey cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at in.per.amt.ignite.cache.ChannelCacheStore.load(ChannelCacheStore.java:19)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can have any kind of backing database by implementing `CacheStore` interface:

https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/persistent-store

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting your key generator?

@CacheConfig(cacheNames = "cache1",keyGenerator = "simpleKeyGenerator")

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3625

Answer (score 0):

So in the below line of code from what you have shared,

```
@Cacheable("cache1")
public List<Channel>  getAllChannels(){
```

the @Cacheable annotation is being used on a method which is not accepting any parameters. Spring cache uses the parameters (if in basic data type) as a key for the cache (response obj as the value). I believe this makes the caching ineffective.

Comment: I think its totally depends on the cache key you use